# Visibility of RelativeLayout change on scrolling Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, adapter, visibility

I am loading some elements (textview/imageview) in a gridview from a database, using an adapter and a content layout with these elements and 4 buttons. What im trying to do is to hide these 4 buttons with a relative layout when the user click on one of them. In my xml I've set the visibility of the relative layout by default to GONE. I change the visibility state to VISIBLE programmatically. 
It works fine. When I click on one button, a dialog is shown, the OK button of this dialog change the relative layout visibility to VISIBLE (as shown in my code). The problem is every time I scroll the gridview, the visibility disappear.
Please what am I doing wrong ?

**xml (gridview model)**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="2dp">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layout_grid"
    android:background="@drawable/title_back"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@+id/criteria_pic"
    android:id="@+id/criteria_text"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="List of criteria"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/criteria_pic"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/rank_layout"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/criteria_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/rank_btn1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_below="@+id/criteria_text"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/rank_btn2"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_below="@+id/criteria_text"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/rank_btn4"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_below="@+id/criteria_text"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/rank_btn5"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_below="@+id/criteria_text"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:id="@+id/check_view"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rank_layout"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rank_layout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="top|right"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/check_ok"
            android:id="@+id/check_image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Adapter**

```
public class GridviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context c;

RelativeLayout RL;
ArrayList<criteria> Critere;
LayoutInflater inflater;


boolean clicked1=false;
boolean clicked2=false;
boolean clicked3=false;
boolean clicked4=false;


private int count = 0;

public GridviewAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<criteria> critere) {
    this.c = c;
    Critere = critere;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}




@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Critere.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return Critere.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService( c.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_model, parent,false);

        TextView nameTxt = v.findViewById(R.id.criteria_text);
        ImageView image = v.findViewById(R.id.criteria_pic);

    final RelativeLayout checked  = v.findViewById(R.id.check_view);
    final LinearLayout ranked = v.findViewById(R.id.rank_layout);


    final String name = Critere.get(position).getName();

    criteria cr = Critere.get(position);

        nameTxt.setText(cr.getName());
        PicassoClient.downloadImage(c, cr.getImageurl(),image);

        final ImageButton btn1 = v.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        final ImageButton btn2 = v.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        final ImageButton btn3 = v.findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        final ImageButton btn4 = v.findViewById(R.id.btn4);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {

                clicked1=true;
                // inflate alert dialog xml
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(c);
                View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_rank, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);

                dialog.setView(dialogView);
                dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.btn_press_rank1);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setTitle(R.string.crit1);
                dialog.setMessage("The " + name + " was very unsatisfiying");
                final EditText userInput = (EditText) dialogView
                        .findViewById(R.id.comment_field);

                dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                      checked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                      ranked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }
                })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.annuler, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                checked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                ranked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });

                final AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clicked2=true;
                // inflate alert dialog xml
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(c);
                View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_rank, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);

                dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.btn_press_rank2);
                dialog.setView(dialogView);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setTitle(R.string.crit2);
                dialog.setMessage("The " + name + " was unsatisfiying");
                final EditText userInput = (EditText) dialogView
                        .findViewById(R.id.comment_field);

                dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        checked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        ranked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.annuler, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //         alert.cancel();
                                checked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                ranked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });

                final AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
                alert.show();

            }
        });

        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clicked3=true;

                // inflate alert dialog xml
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(c);
                View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_rank, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);

                dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.btn_press_rank4);
                dialog.setView(dialogView);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setTitle(R.string.crit3);
                dialog.setMessage("The " + name + " was satisfiying");
                final EditText userInput = (EditText) dialogView
                        .findViewById(R.id.comment_field);

                dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        checked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        ranked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.annuler, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //         alert.cancel();
                                checked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                ranked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });

                final AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
                alert.show();

            }
        });

        btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clicked4=true;

                // inflate alert dialog xml
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(c);
                View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_rank, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);

                dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.btn_press_rank5);
                dialog.setView(dialogView);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setTitle(R.string.crit4);
                dialog.setMessage("The " + name + " was very satisfiying");
                final EditText userInput = (EditText) dialogView
                        .findViewById(R.id.comment_field);

                dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        checked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        ranked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.annuler, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //         alert.cancel();
                                checked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                ranked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });

                final AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
                alert.show();

            }
        });

    return v;

}}
```

**Main Activity**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_criteria);
    new CriteriaActivity.FetchCountTask().execute();

   final GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv);


    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar3);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // get the references of buttons
    btnSelectDate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectDate);
    btnSelectTime=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectTime);

    // Set ClickListener on btnSelectDate
    btnSelectDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Show the DatePickerDialog
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    // Set ClickListener on btnSelectTime
    btnSelectTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

           // startFeedTime();
            // Show the TimePickerDialog
           showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

            new Downloader_review(CriteriaActivity.this, urlAddress, gv).execute();
                }

        // Register  DatePickerDialog listener
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            // the callback received when the user "sets" the Date in the DatePickerDialog
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yearSelected,
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                year = yearSelected;
                month = monthOfYear + 1;
                day = dayOfMonth;
                // Set the Selected Date in Select date Button
                btnSelectDate.setText("Date selected : "+day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
            }
        };

// Register  TimePickerDialog listener
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            // the callback received when the user "sets" the TimePickerDialog in the dialog
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int min) {
                hour = hourOfDay;
                minute = min;
                // Set the Selected Date in Select date Button
                btnSelectTime.setText("Time selected : "+hour+":"+minute);
            }
        };


// Method automatically gets Called when you call showDialog()  method
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // create a new DatePickerDialog with values you want to show
            date = true;
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

            return dialog;
          //  return new DatePickerDialog(this,
          //          mDateSetListener,
          //          mYear, mMonth, mDay);

        // create a new TimePickerDialog with values you want to show
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            time = true;
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);

    }
    return null;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    // Get the notifications MenuItem and
    // its LayerDrawable (layer-list)

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications);
    LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) item.getIcon();
    //  BitmapDrawable iconBitmap = (BitmapDrawable) item.getIcon();
    //  LayerDrawable icon = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable [] { iconBitmap });

    // Update LayerDrawable's BadgeDrawable
    Utils.setBadgeCount(this, icon, mNotificationsCount);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_notifications) {
        // TODO: display unread notifications.
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/*
Updates the count of notifications in the ActionBar.
 */
private void updateNotificationsBadge(int count) {
    mNotificationsCount = count;

    // force the ActionBar to relayout its MenuItems.
    // onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) will be called again.
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
public Action getIndexApiAction() {
    Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
            .setName("Main Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
            .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
            .build();
    return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
            .setObject(object)
            .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
            .build();
}


/*
Sample AsyncTask to fetch the notifications count
*/
class FetchCountTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // example count. This is where you'd
        // query your data store for the actual count.
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Integer count) {
        updateNotificationsBadge(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `RecyclerView` instead of `GridView`. You can get same grid effect by using `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` . Also you will have more control on each item